# Problem with network connection on desktop version

Tags: networking, network-manager, 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop. Connection via Wi-Fi (no LAN port).

Today my network started working strangely, I connected to a Wi-Fi network Telegram works fine! But I can't do `apt-get update` or `apt-get upgrade` even when I start GoogleChrome - I won't be able to visit any site (youtube, google, yandex, etc.). I didn’t change any settings, I also checked the Wi-Fi network on the phone - everything is fine, all sites are working fine. I sometimes use ProtonVPN, but it's now removed from my laptop. Does anyone have an idea what i can do? I was trying to reboot system, shutdown and turn on also doesn't help.

UPD:
Also tried restart router

Answer (score 0):

After many researches my colleague send me command `nmcli connection show` and there was `pvpn-ipv6leak-protection` that is left after ProtonVPN was deleted. Removing this connection with `nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection` and then `reboot` solved the problem.